# Renaming COM ports once I have read in their names

Tags: c#

I have a serial program that I use to send data to Printers.
That part works just great, I use an Epson utility to reassign USB, Parallel, Ethernet printers to a COM port (Epson TM Virtual Port Assignment Tool Ver 8.50)
In this case COM9 for USB printers, COM13 for Ethernet Printers and COM15 for Parallel printers. I know it sounds weird, but it works great.
My issue is I have a simple foreach loop to get the COM port names.
I need to know how to Rename them in the combobox.
    private string[] openComPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    foreach (var item in openComPorts)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }

So now my comboBox1 shows COM1, COM3, COM4, COM9, COM13, COM15.
How do I rename COM9,13,15?
I want them to say COM9-USB, COM13-Ethernet, COM15-Parallel
Any help would be appreciated. 
Target PC is running Windows 7, .NET 4.x, SP1

Comment: Do you know the custom names you want to use ahead of time? (I.E. COM9-USB)

Comment: Yes, COM9-USB, COM13-Ethernet, COM15-Parallel, that way the users don't need to remember which ones are which.

Comment: Do you need ALL the COM ports in the combobox, or only the ones you want custom names for?

Comment: I do need access to all the ports, COM 1, COM 3, COM 4 are regular serial ports (System may have up to 6 regular COM ports, then my special ports above that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a dictionary to use a look-up table for your ports:

```
     string[] openComPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
     Dictionary<string, string> dctLookups = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     // Loop through each COM port name and add to dictionary, giving 
     // it your custom name
     foreach (string comPort in openComPorts)
     {
        // local variable to hold standard name of your port
        string portName = comPort;

        // Check for one of the ports you want a custom name for
        if (comPort == "COM9")
        {
           portName += "-USB";
        }
        else if (comPort == "COM13")
        {
           portName += "-Ethernet";
        }
        else if (comPort == "COM15")
        {
           portName += "-Parallel";
        }

        // Add to <key,value> dictionary with key being portName
        dctLookups.Add(portName, comPort);

        // Add custom name to combobox 
        comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);
     }

     // Get the actual COM port out of your dictionary like this
     try
     {
        string comPort = dctLookups[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        // Port name not in your lookup table
     }
```

Comment: This allows you to maintain a table where the key is a custom value you assign, and the value is the actual COM port name. For the COM ports you don't care about, the key and value will be the same

Comment: Worked 100%, Exectly what I was looking for, Thank you very much!! :)